# I need to update one line in multiple files which are in different folders and all united in one folder

Tags: python, shell

I need to update(Delete one line and add one more line in the same place) one line in multiple files which are in different folders and all united in one folder.My folder structure is as below

Scripts

Component1 (Many components)
     moduleName1
        moduleScript1.groovy
     moduleName2
        moduleScript2.groovy (Many modules)

Component2
     moduleName1
        moduleScript1.groovy
     moduleName2
        moduleScript2.groovy

[image: Folder structure]

I have looked many sed commands but as I understand it is changing in one file not in all. Can someone help me with editing all files together.

Comment: GNU sed can do that with multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code specifically for this, but you could have another python script that opens each file in the folders, and checks specifically for the line of code that you want to change, after that you could have it either alert you of the line location or change it manually... The code might look something like this.

```
   FILE_LIST = []

   REPEAT (AMOUNT OF FILES)
        OPEN(FILE) AS X
        FILE_LIST APPEND X

   REPEAT (RANGE(FILE_LIST))
        IF (LINE YOU WANT TO CHANGE) IN FILE_LIST[FILE] THEN
              ALERT
        ELSE 
              CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for  r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith('.grooviy'):
            update_one_line_in(os.join(r, file))
```

Comment: a verbal explanation would be very helpful